# iOS UITabBar Background Image Hides Unselected Tabs

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, uiappearance

I am using the appearance method for UITabBar to set a Background Image on my tab bar.  When I do this, the unselected icons on the tab bar do not appear any.  What do I need to do to make sure those are visible, even when not selected?

Comment: can you put some snippet of tabbar?

Comment: [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: you have to use setBarTintColor: to set the background color for IOS 7.

Comment: for selected/unselected image do this: [self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seleted.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nselected.png"]];